# I can't get a rules based style to render properly in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I've got a shapefile, and I'm trying to create a style so that it has the colours red, yellow or green based on one column, and a thickness based on another. 
[image: screenshot]

The problem is that it only seems to render the smallest 'layer' FRC3,4,5. When I get rid of the ranges it renders correctly for all of the segments though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've worked out my problem, the second column I was basing colour off of was null for some values, stopping them rendering correctly